# NSTableView: Displaying An Expanded Row (Resizing on the Fly)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

OK. I looked through the suggestions (which often answer my questions before I ask). I haven't found what I need.

I know that I'm doing something wrong. I do this all the time in iOS (UIKit), but tables in NS (Mac) are pretty darn different from UIKit.

I have a view-based NSTableView. Each row has exactly 1 column. This column has a view with a header (21 points high), and an expanded view (the row is 420 points high). There is a disclosure triangle on the left of the header that toggles these two modes.

The controller is also the table datasource and delegate. I have the row height callback returning the correct values for the view.

The header displays fine. I set the row heights to 21, and only the headers are shown. This clips the main view.

[image: A row of closed headers]

When a disclosure triangle is toggled, a row expands its height to reveal the entire view:

[image: An open row]

Simple enough, eh?

The problem is that B is not displayed. I just get a blank (However, A is correctly displayed). The items are there, just not being displayed. The table row is the correct height (this can be verified by using alternating row colors).

I've tried setting setNeedsLayout/Draw on the views.

Any clues on what I may be doing wrong?

I'm willing to bet that I'm doing something boneheaded, and I'll keep looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

Using `noteHeighOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:`? It's an NSTableView function, not a delegate function.

In the documentation for the delegate function `tableView:heightOfRow` it declares:

> Although table views may cache the returned values, you should ensure that this method is efficient. When you change a row's height you must invalidate the existing row height by calling noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:. NSTableView automatically invalidates its entire row height cache when reloadData and noteNumberOfRowsChanged are called.

As it mentions, NSTableView's `reloadData` is often the lazy way to fix your sort of issue as well.

Your table controller shouldn't need the setsNeeds[whatever] methods you tried.

Also, speaking of disclosure triangles and such, on OSX there is a NSTableView subclass called NSOutlineView that handles item expansion if you mangle your data into a poorly documented tree format.  I actually wouldn't recommend it if your data's not a natural tree, but you should be aware of it, even if its API sucks.  Oh, and the expansion when clicking the disclosure triangle is animated.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check that out. I -sort of- fixed it. The original view was segregated into 2 subviews (header and body). I removed the items from these subviews, and put them all in the main view. They now display. Very weird.

Comment: Oh, interesting.  I believe the tableview or whatever displays only subframes of the cells if the display is clipped-- I had some ugly scroll issues when using drawRect in a cellView-- so I guess needsDisplay could be useful, but I don't know.  TableView should handle that when you mark the row height as dirty.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep messing with it, and see where it goes.

Comment: I'm also wondering if it might have something to do with each row having its own viewController. The row viewController is not associated with the table. It simply controls the behavior of the row view, itself.

Comment: That is not typical with OSX tables.  I'd be worried you're keeping a pointer to a recycled cellview.  The tableview owns and reuses the cellviews.  I'm not sure what you'd do in a NSViewController that you couldn't to in a NSTableRowView or CellView subclass.  Though I don't see why you *shouldn't* have a custom view under the control of a VC.

Comment: Each row is a device status control. It does a lot; displaying state and allowing manipulation. I really need a controller. Maybe a table is not a good construct?

Comment: View-based tables were stapled onto the older spreadsheet tables.  But they should work.  It's just clunky-- UITableView solves a lot of the clunkiness.

Comment: You would want to ensure the owner in `makeViewWithIdentifier:owner` is your view controller... and that seems to ensure you must have a separate Nib for the custom row/cell view.

Comment: I instantiate the controllers directly from the nib. Maybe I should use makeViewWithIdentifier.

Comment: Yeeeahh...I'm not really feeling this. I have a feeling that an NSTableView isn't the appropriate container for this honker. I may have to write my own row display class. The caching is irrelevant, as I need to keep each view loaded, live and unreusable at all times.

Comment: Awesome! You are correct! I'd completely forgotten about that.